# How to create an array of indices given the number of times the indices should repeat?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indices

**How to create an array of indices given the number of times the indices should repeat?**

Given:

```
[ 3, 2, 5]
```

The desired output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ 3, 2, 5])


list(chain(*[[i]*v for i,v in enumerate(x)]))
```

It gives the desired result but is there a simpler way to achieve the desired output?